# PHP connection refused although i am still getting the data

Tags: php, next.js

so this is a bit of a weird situation. I have a php server running on a remote location and a next.js app to interact with it. All was fine but now all of a sudden the login function is giving me a connection refused error along with the data.
Here is the screenshot of the response:
[image]

Now here is the login function:

```
 public function login(){
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
        header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers");

        $client = Flight::db();
        $request = Flight::request();
        $db = $client->deltab_app;
        $collection = $db->users;
        $email = $request->data->email;
        $password = $request->data->password;
        $result = $collection->findOne(
            [
                'email' => $email
            ]
        );
        if (empty($result)) {
            echo json_encode([
                'status' => 404,
                'error' => 'Template Not Found'
            ]);
            return;
        }

        if(password_verify($password,$result->password)){
            $token = array(
                "iss" =>  "http://example.org",
                "aud" => "http://example.com",
                "iat" => 1356999524,
                "nbf" => 1357000000,
                "data" => array(
                    "id" => $result->_id,
                    "email" => $email
                )
            );

            // set response code
            http_response_code(200);

            // generate jwt
            $jwt = JWT::encode($token,'weareone');
            echo json_encode(
                array(
                    "message" => "200",
                    "jwt" => $jwt,
                    "name" => $result->name
                )
            );
        } else{
            http_response_code(404);
            echo json_encode(
                array(
                    "message" => "Invalid Username or password",
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

I can confirm that all other functions are working correctly. But somehow this is behaving like this even though i remember it was working fine and that I haven't even touched it again.

EDIT: If it helps i am using axios to make a post request to this endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its my fault. It seems the error came when i was trying to establish a socket connection on the root of the index.php file. Solved now.